# Nothing is upgrading or updating in Ubuntu 20.04.,,dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic (--configure):

Tags: grub2, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Whenever I try to install a new package on Ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic (5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic (5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic (5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.13.0-30-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic (5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.13.0-28-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.13.0-27-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: Debian: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic
 linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic
 linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `sudo mv /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak`  `sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub
 /etc/default/` this error is not since yesterday. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I hope you have enough space.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
The [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394792/nothing-is-upgrading-or-updating-in-ubuntu-20-04-dpkg-error-processing-packag#comment2413815_1394792) by [nobody](https://askubuntu.com/users/966203/nobody), worked for me:

```
sudo mv /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub  /etc/default/
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

These commands remove the current grub configuration at `/etc/default/grub`, and restores the default grub configuration from `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`

Comment: FYI: This is **NOT** an NAA (not an answer). This exactly answers the question. @Flaggers.